# Adding Value To New Cell If Parameter Match For Other Cell

Tags: r

I have created a new empty column in a `data.frame` `data`:

```
data$new_column <- 0
```

Above value will be updated after comparing all rows based on a certain condition. Pseudo code would be like:

```
if ( data$column_x == X & data$column_y == Y ){
    data$new_column <- "New Data" # Only one cell should be update based on row & column ID
}
```

I am not sure how I can update other column based on the condition of two different column. I tried extracting `row` ID, and based on that tried updating new column, but it's not working out:

```
row_id <- which(data$column_x == X & data$column_y == Y)
data[row_id, data$new_column ] <- "New Data"
```

**Sample Data**

```
 column_x   column_y  new_column 
   -34         12         0
   -36         20         0
   -36         12         0
   -34         18         0
   -34         10         0
   -35         24         0
   -35         16         0
   -33         22         0
   -33         14         0
   -35         22         0
```

Can anyone please suggest correct approach for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
data <- data.frame(column_x = c(-34, -36, -36, -34, -34, -35, -35, -33, -33, -35), column_y = c(12, 20, 12, 18, 10, 24, 16, 22, 14, 22), new_column = 0)

data$new_column[data$column_x == -36 & data$column_y == 12] <- 123

data

   column_x column_y new_column
1       -34       12          0
2       -36       20          0
3       -36       12        123
4       -34       18          0
5       -34       10          0
6       -35       24          0
7       -35       16          0
8       -33       22          0
9       -33       14          0
10      -35       22          0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` approach :

```
data <- data %>% mutate(., new_col = ifelse(column_x ==X && column_y ==Y, 'new_values', 0)
```

This will create a new column called new_col with 0 and new_values on the cells where the condition inside the ifelse function is true.